# HTACCESS image url rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have this image

```
http://domain.com/images/2.png
```

I want this URL

```
http://domain.com/images/sale-item.png
```

to open above image, NO Redirect please.

In short the URL http://domain.com/images/sale-item.png will open this image http://domain.com/images/2.png

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` then use this as **first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(_images/corners)/sale-item\.png/?$ $1/2.png [L,NC]
```

Comment: its not working for some reason see this please
http://www.topfurniture.co.uk/_images/corners/2.png
to 
http://www.topfurniture.co.uk/_images/corners/sale-item.png

Comment: You have `_images` in your URL but `images` in your question. In which .htaccess have you placed it? Also can you show your rule because URL also has `/corners/`

Comment: .htaccess is in main root directory
I am trying this in .htaccess root directory
RewriteRule ^(corners)/sale-item\.png$ $1/2.png [L,NC]

Comment: There is some wrong rule on your site adding trailing slash in front of this png file. If in root then you will need to match `_images/` also.